# True meaning of triliteral root ta,mim,noon

Tags: arabic

In many places in the Quran different internal states have been mentioned. One is any derivative from the triliteral root **ta,mim,noon**.

For example [chapter 13, verse 28](https://quran.com/13/28) where it says:

> الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا وَتَطْمَئِنُّ قُلُوبُهُمْ بِذِكْرِ اللَّهِ أَلَا بِذِكْرِ اللَّهِ تَطْمَئِنُّ الْقُلُوبُ

Now this has been translated to a couple of meanings ranging from *serenity* to *assuredness*.

But these meanings are somehow not the same. Being assured in many situations might equal to having inner peace.

But there are times that you don't have inner peace, yet you are assured about the situation.

Could you please clarify the true, etymological meaning of this triliteral root?

**Update**:

By *true* I mean etymological meaning. A meaning that was dominant when the Quran was revealed to Muhammad.
For sources, please go to https://quran.com/13/28 and from settings menu, select all English translations. You'll see these translations:

- are composed
- find rest
- are assured
- find satisfaction
- find peace
- find comfort

Comment: I don't think that there is a single, true meaning to a root. They have a range of meanings which is exactly what you have found. It's just as true for any other language, and not just Arabic.

Comment: ...as looking through any dictionary would show you. Or just reflecting on the use of your own language.

Comment: This sounds weird and doesn't seem to be related to Islam. I don't even get what you mean which ta, mom, noon? You made strange claims and didn't even share a source for them.

Comment: What exactly does it mean to be "the true" meaning of a root? A root covers a variety of meanings and can be made into several words, that's why it is called a root rather than one word.